# jquery animation grow and shrink issue

Tags: jquery, animation, html, shapes

I have made a a basic html website and I have button two butttons one make a the J query square (`<div id="ccal" style="background:#2E2EFE;height:150px;width:150px;">`) bigger (id="ccalicon") and the other button (id="ccalmax") to make it even bigger.

**1st button**

```
$("#ccalicon").click(function(){
  $("#ccal").animate({width:500,height:300},"slow");
});
```

However when I click the second button I want it to make the square bigger but it it grows and shrinks (width:50,height:300) again!

```
$("#ccalmax").click(function(){
$("#ccal").animate({width:700,height:700},"slow");
});
```

Can anyone shed some light on this and why this is happening and what I should do to stop it from shrinking again?
Thanks,

Comment: it is working fine for me on http://jsfiddle.net/FpJN6/

Comment: Same [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AYrq2/1/). You must have a syntax error or something else in your code.